# finding CNF and a logically Logically equivalent DNF for Propositional form (p→(q→r))

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I can write the truth table for (p→(q→r)) but i was not able to find the required CNF and a logically Logically equivalent DNF for Propositional form  (p→(q→r)) . It's confusing.

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1):

Since $A\rightarrow B$ is defined as $\lnot A\lor B$, we can write $(1)$ as $(2)$.

\begin{equation}\tag{1}
(p\rightarrow(q\rightarrow r))
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}\tag{2}
(\lnot p)\lor(\lnot q)\lor r
\end{equation}

Formula $(2)$ is in disjunctive normal form already, since logical OR is the major connective. Note that we can also form the conjunction of $(2)$ with logical true (denoted here as $1$), which makes a CNF formula.

\begin{equation}\tag{3}
\big((\lnot p)\lor(\lnot q)\lor r\big)\land 1
\end{equation}

It is common to refer $(2)$ as a [CNF expression with 1 conjunct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form#Examples_and_non-examples).